# how to get a Google Maps API v2 release key

Tags: android, google-maps

My app, that uses the google mapview, is ready to be released.  My testing was done using the google maps key that I obtained back when I started the project.  I am told that this key will not work for my release version and that I need another key for my release version.

All of the posts in this forum and every other place I can find discuss getting a version 1 key.  For instance there is documentation on how to get a MD5 fingerprint (whatever that is) for the version 1 key.

How can I get the key I need for version 2?

Edit:
To make this question a little clearer, I already have my 64bit app key, a keystore file, an alais and a password.  It looks like I need a SHA-1 fingerprint that can somehow be obtained using the keytool program.  I didn't need the keytool program to get what I have as I used the Eclipse Export Wizard.
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google documents the entire process [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Specifically, if you need help finding out how to use `keytool`, expand the section titled "Displaying the release certificate fingerprint."

Comment: This process of getting the SHA1 key is actually kind of a pain. If you don't bother with it, the Google maps API will actually tell you in LogCat the SHA1 fingerprint you need. It says something like this:
11-06 14:45:11.326: E/Google Maps Android API(21443): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.yourpackage.uri, API Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Certificate Fingerprint: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Does not work for me, the google documentation is not conform to their interface. Impossible to get the key.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was my problem. 2 different key are needed, one for debug and one for release

Comment: The link is for a deg key not a release key.

Answer (score 4):

**To get SHA-1 key:**

For Linux or OS X, open a terminal window and enter the following:

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -aliasandroiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

`keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

You should see output similar to this:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jan 01, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4aa9b300
Valid from: Mon Jan 01 08:04:04 UTC 2013 until: Mon Jan 01 18:04:04 PST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  AE:9F:95:D0:A6:86:89:BC:A8:70:BA:34:FF:6A:AC:F9
     SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

The line that begins SHA1 contains the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint. The fingerprint is the sequence of 20 two-digit hexadecimal numbers separated by colons.

Comment: if you use  GNU/Linux  see this answerd http://stackoverflow.com/a/15721056/3741698