# Google api map V2 not displaying with signed apk in device

Tags: android

I am displaying MAP using google map Api V2 i successfully displayed it in device when am running through my PC but now i am signing my application via export signed apk and made as .keystore and .apk and it made a certificate and now i am using that apk file and runnning the application but the map does not displayed just showing white screen, even i made a release key using 
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html  and i succesfully performed all the steps given in the link but then too the map is not displaying, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: did you created sha1 finger print key using your release keysotre and added that in your Google api console's app.

Comment: yes its all done but then too its not working when i made a certificate and used that signed apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to sign your maps with release key ;) you signed your map with debug.keystore

[how to get a Google Maps API v2 release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384587/how-to-get-a-google-maps-api-v2-release-key)

[Google Maps v2 Getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

My `public class VentanaMapa extends FragmentActivity`
when `private GoogleMap mMap;`

```
status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    Intent intentErrorMapa = null;
    switch (status) {
    case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
        SupportMapFragment SupportMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = SupportMap.getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        new ObtenerEnvio().execute(_empAlbaran, _codAlbaran.toString(),
                _lineaAlbaran.toString());
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
        Toast.makeText(VentanaMapa.this, R.string.ErrorMapaServiceMissing,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
        Toast.makeText(VentanaMapa.this, R.string.ErrorMapaSignRequired,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
        Toast.makeText(VentanaMapa.this, R.string.ErrorMapaServiceUpdate,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 999:
        Toast.makeText(VentanaMapa.this, R.string.ErrorCargarMapa,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
```

My Map.xml:

```
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageButtonAnteriorMapa"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

1) create a release key, for sign your app. SHA1 that you have you need to go to Google Api console. Create new Android key like SHA1_number;your.package
2) with this key you need to add in your manifest like:
`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_key_for_release" />`
your put that code before `</application>`
that's it. check logcat to see exactly which message you recive from Google Maps

Comment: so how to sign the maps with release key ?

Comment: but these all things i had done i used to run the keytool command in cmd and then i used to get the sha1 key and then i created android key using that sha1 key  with ;and my package name then i got a key and m using that key but then too its not working

Comment: are you in release or in debug mode?

Comment: first i was in debug mode so map is working fine when i ran the application via my pc connected to the device but now i want to upload my apk so at that time i made a certificate and i got the final apk that is m going to upload in that map is not working

Comment: if you need i can post my manifest too. But your problem is in key ...., why?because i had same problem like yours

Comment: so can u pls let me know about the key in manifest file how to make it release key ? actually my code is working perfectly but i also suppose the problem would be of the key that is been used in manifest file.

Comment: this is what i done for creating the key but then too not working when signed otherwise the process which u told is done fully

Comment: already but i thought of installing the signed apk directly via mass storage and i suppose it would not be possible thnks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot got the same problem and fix it by following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#the_google_maps_api_key

Answer (score 3):

You must need to create new map api key with your newely create keystore and put it on Google Map Api Console page. Use below command:

```
PATH OF YOUR KEYTOOL FILE/keytool -list -v -keystore YOURKEYSTORENAME
```

You will get SHA-1, save it. Go to Google api console page, create new Android key using this SHA-1 and put newely created key into your app. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I Faced the Same Problem,Finally Got a Solution, Kindly check your Developer Account,It have permission for Api key generation follow this steps to show your map in google play signed apk

```
1. Create the Api using Debugging SHA1.
(eg)F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F:F0:0F;com.blabla.app
2.Create the Api using Relased SHA1 from appname.keystore.
(eg)F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83:F2:83;com.blabla.app
 you have an option to create on this api in single textfield in developerId api console page.

This kind of option are available only in developer account.Try it.Thank you.
Please refer the following Image if u have any doubt.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Google API console have you add your `signed` sha1 Key and change it in your `Manifest.xml` ?

Because, `signed` and `debug keystore` and completely different, with **Eclipse**, when you **Export** your project as an Android Application, you choose a keystore and before clicking `finish`, there is a sha1 key at the bottom of the window. You've to add this specific key in the API Console.

Comment: while running the application from my pc via eclipse it shows the map but when i am making the certificate at that time i am using mass stoarge and using the apk directly so no logcat is there

Answer (score 0):

try this

**1.first create the  .APK file in eclipse in the console as shown this see this image**

[image: Console]

**2.copy the SHA1 key and then create the API Key**
     using this  .[Google APIs Console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect)

**3 and past the API key into ur project and then create the APK file**

Answer (score 0):

To find out the Android SHA1 fingerprint for release keystore, follow these steps:

Open terminal
Change the directory to the JDK bin directory, mine was jdk1.7.0_05 (could be different for you).

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
```

Next we have to run the keytool.exe. Use the following line to get the SHA1 fingerprint.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

Example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

It will prompt for a password.
Enter the password, you will get the SHA1 and MD5 fingerprint.