# Google map not showing in my application

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi Everyone,
            I am developing a android application related to club based.In that i start my project with built target(google api) and finally i completed my application.The final module from my client was he need a map in that application.After a very deep analyse i found google was updated the google map version become 1.2.To use that we can set the built target(android 4.2) only.So now i have no idea to do this..can anyone suggest for me how to implement google map in my application with built target google api either how to change my built target to android 4.2??????

Comment: use google map api v2 by using fragments

Comment: [see this answer maybe help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741100/google-api-map-v2-not-displaying-with-signed-apk-in-device/17741138#17741138

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add the follwing to your manifest
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


//add this following to your manifest below the activity tag

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_apikey" />
```

//your Activity should be like this

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourmapid))
        .getMap();

    }
```

//your xml should be like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: you must import fragmentactivity class and add google-playservices-lib project as a reference library

Comment: deen thanks for your suggestion..But it will work only if we set a built in target android4.2 but my project target is google api..so it is just showing a tiles not a map....

Comment: are you using SHA key to generate map api key?

Comment: Are you refer the google-play-services_lib project as a reference library?

Comment: s i did that also deen