# Blank Google Map (Works on Emulator but NOT Works on Device S5)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an android app which uses Maps API.

It works very good on my Emulator (Genymotion). See the image.

[image]

but when I generate a signed apk and send it to my mobile (Samsung S5) it not works. See the image.

[image]

What I already did:

1:Check the key.

2:Check the release and debug api file, the has the same key.

3:Use the permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Google Map Api must have a API user account key. You can create one from Google Engine Dashboard

Comment: @zIronManBox I already added my own key which generated by google using my own package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API_Key you generated previously was for debug keystore. Use the same keystore to get the SHA-1 key and generate API_Key that you have used for signing the apk. Then replace the new API_Key in your manifest and then generate signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a signed APK, you have to generate a new API key for the Google Map and update it in the API console. The API key used with the debug APK will not work.

Check your logcat, it probably shows an Authorization Failure message.

if you need any other help go to this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17741138/4919210

Comment: I already added my own key which generated by google using my own package name.