# Maps API not displaying in my debug .apk

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an app that uses Google maps in fragments. It works great when I run it from studio, but when I created a debug .apk to test it out on other devices, the map fragments load the mapview, but there's no map. I've read a lot on the site about new API keys and tried those solutions out, but they don't seem to work.  I generated a new API key using the keytool as descirbed in the developers guide, and then rebuilt the .apk, but that didn't work.  I'm really at my wits end here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You got the fingerprint from your debug key and added it to the google console?

Comment: Yes. That's the number you get when you run the keytool, correct?  The one that is something like 0D:A4....  I ran the keytool and the fingerprint was the same as the one studio gave me to get the first key.  I used that to generate a new key, then signed and generated a new apk.

Comment: Check this SO question [26778713](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778713/android-google-map-v2-not-showing-map-for-release-apk) and [17741100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741100/google-api-map-v2-not-displaying-with-signed-apk-in-device) if it can help you :)

Comment: So you generated a new key, used that key to sign your apk, and added the new key's fingerprint on the google console?  What is your process for generating an apk?  And let's see your gradle file.

Comment: I got it to work.  After I generated the signed apk with the new fingerprint I went to build apk and that seemed to do the trick.  The apk that was built then worked on other devices.