# User location is not displaying in signed apk

Tags: android

I have build a signed apk and it is working fine except it is getting crashed on the Google Map as it is not showing current location of the user. the .apk from the project is working fine and is showing current location of the user.

Answer (score 0):

you need to sign your maps with release key ;) you signed your map with debug.keystore

[how to get a Google Maps API v2 release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384587/how-to-get-a-google-maps-api-v2-release-key)

[Google Maps v2 Getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

1) create a release key, for sign your app. SHA1 that you have you need to go to Google Api console. Create new Android key like SHA1_number;your.package

2) with this key you need to add in your manifest like:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_key_for_release" />
```

**put that code inside  application tag**

That's it. check logcat to see exactly which message you recive from Google Maps

Comment: I have used the build SHA1 key and created release key and tested the signed apk in different android phones but XOLO mobiles are not showing current location of the user. Please help.