# How to change google map api key from debug to release in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-googleapiclient

I have created an android app and generated a debug key for google maps api using debug sha certificate. Now I want to generate a key in release mode but android api manager in android developer console in not giving me an option to change the sha certificate to release. How to do it. I have already generated the sha-release certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a Google Maps API v2 release key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384587/how-to-get-a-google-maps-api-v2-release-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generate your hash using your sign apk. and than update your sha1 in google developer console.

Comment: how to update my sha1 in google developer console i have generated it but not able to update it in google developer console

Comment: First open google developer console then choose your project.
Then go to Credential and see "OAuth 2.0 client IDs"
and open android client key for your "project name"
Then update your new SHA1.

Comment: I have genereated a client id using that. Now, where should i use that OAuth 2.0 client Id. what is its use

Comment: OAuth 2.0 client Id is not use
In OAuth 2.0 client Id see Android key for your project
Than change your SHA1

Comment: when i created oauth2.0 client id i used the release sha-1 certificate. Does that update my sha-1 certificate?

Comment: yaa. Just change your SHA1.

Comment: now when i use the newly generated key in debug mode. will it still work?

Comment: when you create sign apk just generate new SHA1 from just use new sign apk

Comment: It is recommended to use two different key 1) Debug and 2) release. You can use different build types to change the api key to release build using configuration file like `gradle.properties`.