# Location project not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Bear with me, I am a good java developer, but I have been learning android for only one month. I am currently creating an app, where one key element of the app is to share your current location with the help of Google API location services.

I found [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android) nice guide on how to get started with the location concept in android. Some may argue it is a little outdated, as its 2 years old now, but I thought I might give it a shot anyway.

Even though I love much about android studio, I have ran into so many complicated problems, that I almost feel like giving up. For example the builder complained that I have more than 64k method references, I looked up the problem, and found a workaround with a one liner in my gradle file. Later I faced a problem with heap allocation, and again I had to just paste in this one liner so that more space was allocated for my app(no where is this feature explained, you are just supposed to throw it in!).

At last my app is up and running on my phone, but instead of showing me a nice map with a marker of my current location, all I see is a white screen with the google text in the bottom left corner. All I can do is wonder, what is wrong?

A list of what has been done:

-I have the API-key, and put it correctly in my manifest
-I followed the step-by-step guide closely
-I have tried debugging with logcat by using Log and tagging every method

My last hope is to share this with you guys, and hope that some more experienced guys will point out my error(s)!

So here it goes.

Here is the MapsActivity class:

```
Imports...

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected");

        try
        {
            //if we get permissions from user to use this service, this will be executed
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location == null)
            {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
            else
            {
                handleNewLocation(location);
            };
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            //here we did not get the permission
            Log.i(TAG, "Did not get permissions");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try
            {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            }
            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "heresthelocation "+location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

And if needed, here is my androidmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


</application>
```

Comment: As for the blank map, that is an issue with the API key configuration.   Look at the logs for an error regarding that....

Comment: I already correctly added the key to both the google_maps xml and the manifest. What is wrong?E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                           Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                           Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                            API Key:

Comment: Are you sure that the Google Maps API is enabled in your google developer console?

Comment: No I am not. How can I easily check this?

Comment: Go here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/  And click on `Google Maps Android API`

Comment: Ok thanks, but I can only click "disable", so I guess I already enabled it? This is so so confusing...

Comment: Is the API key that you created an Android API Key?  Also, make sure that you have the SHA1 entered correctly.

Comment: I am completely sure Daniel. I followed the guide provided in the xml closely. The key is in the right place. I cannot figure why it does not authorize correctly. Is there a way I could create a new key for my project?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't completely explain how to get your SHA1 fingerprint.  Did you by chance use all sevens like their placeholder?  You will need to get the SHA1 fingerprints for your debug keystore initially, and then for your release keystore when you are making signed release builds.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33844052/4409409